# In Firebug Network Panel is there a way to sort requests by the order in which they occurred

Tags: firefox, firebug

If you sort the requests in the Firebug Network Panel by domain, is it then possible to re-sort the requests, to see the requests in the order in which they occurred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. Just click the *Timeline* column header twice.

Sebastian